# Create random data during Promise.all

Tags: javascript, mongodb, es6-promise, random-seed

I'd like to create a mock data based on a JSON array to test front-end.

Object structure in the JSON array:

Mock:

```
{
  category: string,
  items: string[]
}
```

Category:

```
{
  name: string,
  products: Product[]
}
```

Product:

```
{
  name: string,
  prices: Price[]
}
```

Price:

```
{
  date: Date,
  value: number
}
```

I'd like to create random `Price`s for each `Product`, therefore I created the following helper function:

```
// Creates Price array with random values within a given time window
// `times` is a `lodash` function
const getRandomPrices = (numberOfDays, minValue, maxValue) => times(numberOfDays, n => ({
  date: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - n)),
  value: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue) + minValue
}))
```

And I’m seeding my MongoDB database with the following function:

```
// data is Mock[]
// Price, Product and Category are MongoDB schemas
const createCategories = data.map(async c => {
  const createProducts = c.items.map(async p => {
    const prices = getRandomPrices(15, 100, 1000)
    const createPrices = prices.map(price => Price.create(price))

    return Product.create({
      name: p,
      prices: await Promise.all(createPrices)
    })
  })

  return Category.create({
    name: c.category,
    products: await Promise.all(createProducts)
  })
})

await Promise.all(createCategories)
console.log('done')
```

My problem is that I have same `Price` data for any `Product` in any `Category` and my questions are:

- how can I randomize prices?
- where am I doing wrong?

Comment: So I logged `prices` and it's all having unique `value`s. That doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, and you're right. I was checking results via graphiql actually, didn't think of dumping it to the console. I guess the problem is related GraphQL resolver then. Thanks.